# wants string output which is in between 5th and 6th ‘/’

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Input looks like

```
/nfs/site/disks/mtl_workdisk_003/mtlmedia/filter_bundle2846/regress/
/nfs/site/disks/mtl_workdisk_003/mtl3d/filter_bundle2846/regress/
/nfs/site/disks/mtl_workdisk_003/etl66/filter_bundle2846/regress/
```

Output should be

```
mtlmedia
mtl3d
etl66
```

I am able to successfully get the output but is there anyway to simplify it using some other functions or method ?

```
declare @T table
(
InputString varchar(max)
);

insert into @T values
('/nfs/site/ssd/mtl_workdisk_1/mediatek/filter_candle46/regression/'),
('/nfs/location/disks/mtl_workdisk_003/mtl3d/filter_candle2846/regress/'),
('/nfs/place/disks/mtl_workdisk_003/etl1266/bundle2846/regress/') ;

select -- P1.Pos, P2.Pos, P3.Pos,P4.Pos,P5.Pos,P6.Pos,
substring(InputString, P5.Pos + 1, P6.Pos - P5.Pos - 1) as OutputString
from @T
cross apply (select (charindex('/', InputString))) as P1(Pos)
cross apply (select (charindex('/', InputString, P1.Pos+1))) as P2(Pos)
cross apply (select (charindex('/', InputString, P2.Pos+1))) as P3(Pos)
cross apply (select (charindex('/', InputString, P3.Pos+1))) as P4(Pos)
cross apply (select (charindex('/', InputString, P4.Pos+1))) as P5(Pos)
cross apply (select (charindex('/', InputString, P5.Pos+1))) as P6(Pos) ;
```

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: SQL Server Version is 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approaches, based on built-in `XML` or `JSON` support, are possible options:

Statement, based on XML:

```
SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(InputString, '/', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')
FROM @t
```

Statement, based on JSON:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(InputString, '/', '","'), '"]'), '$[5]')
FROM @T
```

Result:

```
mediatek
mtl3d
etl1266
```

Notes:

JSON support is available from SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Any leads on how to do the same in SQL Server Version 2012 ?

Comment: @sgsergio The XML approach works with SQL Server 2012, for JSON approach you need SQL Server 2016+.

Answer (score 1):

If you always know the root of the path and just want the first subfolder name after that, you could get a substring based on the length of the root combined with a charindex looking for the first slash after the root.

```
declare @paths as table(fullpath varchar(max))

insert into @paths values ('/nfs/site/disks/mtl_workdisk_003/mtlmedia/filter_bundle2846/regress/')
insert into @paths values ('/nfs/site/disks/mtl_workdisk_003/mtl3d/filter_bundle2846/regress/')
insert into @paths values ('/nfs/site/disks/mtl_workdisk_003/etl66/filter_bundle2846/regress/')

declare @root as varchar(max) = '/nfs/site/disks/mtl_workdisk_003/'
declare @startPos as int = len(@root) + 1

select substring(fullpath, @startPos, CHARINDEX('/',fullpath,@startPos) - @startPos) filename
from @paths
where CHARINDEX('/',fullpath,@startPos) > 0
```

I did the where clause at the end to prevent any errors if for some reason, there was no subfolder (slash) found after the root.

If you always know the ending of the path as well, you could just use a REPLACE to remove the ending and not even have to search for the "/" with the CHARINDEX.